# Need some help calculating accumulated data in Microsoft Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I want to calculate the accumulated data of the field BalanceCalculationA, based on the date of transaction (TrxDate) and member's name (MemberName). An image of what the query looks like currently could be seen in the attachment below. I have tried editing the SQL statement to calculate the accumulated data, to no avail. I'm stumped. Here is my code:

```
SELECT MoneyJournal.[GroupNumber], MoneyJournal.[MemberName], MoneyJournal.[TrxDate], MoneyJournal.[Deposits], MoneyJournal.[Withdrawals], [Deposits]-[Withdrawals] AS BalanceCalculationA, 

(SELECT sum(abc.[BalanceCalculationA])
FROM [MoneyJournal Query] as abc
WHERE abc.[MemberName]=MoneyJournal.[MemberName] 
AND abc.[TrxDate]<=MoneyJournal.[TrxDate]) AS [BalanceCalculationB]

FROM MoneyJournal;
```

If anyone could provide me with a workaround that could calculate accumulated data without needing to edit the SQL statements, you are absolutely welcome to do so. Any help is much appreciated.
[Image Attachment click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPNgH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you need to pull data from the same table, not another query:

```
SELECT 
    MoneyJournal.[GroupNumber], 
    MoneyJournal.[MemberName], 
    MoneyJournal.[TrxDate], 
    MoneyJournal.[Deposits], 
    MoneyJournal.[Withdrawals], 
    [Deposits]-[Withdrawals] AS BalanceCalculationA,    
        (SELECT SUM(abc.[Deposits]-abc.[Withdrawals])
        FROM MoneyJournal AS abc
        WHERE abc.[MemberName]=MoneyJournal.[MemberName] 
        AND abc.[TrxDate]<=MoneyJournal.[TrxDate]) AS 
    [BalanceCalculationB]
FROM 
    MoneyJournal;
```